# execute batch with oracle prepared statement

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I try to add batch prepared statement with following code:

```
Connection c = ...
PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(query1);
ps.setObject(....)
...
ps.addBatch(query2); // SqlException : Unsupported feature
```

Does not oracle jdbc driver support batches, or I am doing something wrong?

I am using oracle thin driver. Version from MANIFEST.MF `Implementation-Version: 11.2.0.1.0`.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported feature
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.addBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9803)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.addBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:285)
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedStatement.addBatch(WrappedStatement.java:731)
        at <application classes>
```

Comment: You cannot execute two different statements in a single batch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating a `PreparedStatement` using `query1` and adding `query2` to an already prepared statetement of which it doesn't belong to.

If you are using `PreparedStatement`, I suggest using the `PreparedStatement.addBatch()` method instead.

```
PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(query1);
ps.setObject(....);
ps.addBatch(); //Voila
```

Answer (score 3):

The JDBC specification explicitly requires `PreparedStatement` (and `CallableStatement`) implementations to throw an `SQLException` if you call any of the `execute`, `executeUpdate`, `executeQuery` or `addBatch` methods that accept a query string.

See for example the Javadoc on [`Statement.addBatch(String sql)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#addBatch%28java.lang.String%29):

> **Throws:**
>   `SQLException` - if a database access error occurs, this method is called on a closed `Statement`, the driver does not support batch updates, **the method is called on a `PreparedStatement` or `CallableStatement`**

(emphasis mine)

With `PreparedStatement` you can only use the `setXXX` methods, then use [`addBatch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch%28%29) to batch sets of parameter values for the prepared query (and repeat that for a different set of parameter values). You cannot batch different queries the way you can with a normal `Statement`.

The way to use batching with `PreparedStatement` is roughly like this:

```
try (PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(query1)) {
    while (moreParameterValueSets) {
        ps.setObject(....)
        //...
        ps.addBatch();
    }
    ps.executeBatch();
}
```