# Batch processing JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, properties, dao

I am practicing JDBC batch processing and having errors:

error 1: Unsupported feature
error 2: Execute cannot be empty or null

```
Property files include:
itemsdao.updateBookName = Update Books set bookname = ? where books.id = ?
itemsdao.updateAuthorName = Update books set authorname = ? where books.id = ?
```

I know I can execute about DML statements in one update, but I am practicing batch processing in JDBC.

Below is my method

```
public void update(Item item) {
            String query = null;

        try {
            connection = DbConnector.getConnection();
            property = SqlPropertiesLoader.getProperties("dml.properties");
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);

            if ( property == null )
            {
                Logging.log.debug("dml.properties does not exist. Check property loader or file name is spelled right");
                return;
            }

            query = property.getProperty("itemsdao.updateBookName");
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            statement.setString(1, item.getBookName());
            statement.setInt(2, item.getId());
            statement.addBatch(query);

            query = property.getProperty("itemsdao.updateAuthorName");
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            statement.setString(1, item.getAuthorName());
            statement.setInt(2, item.getId());
            statement.addBatch(query);

            statement.executeBatch();
            connection.commit();

        }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Logging.log.error("Connection class does not exist", e);
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
            Logging.log.error("Violating PK constraint",e);
        }

        //helper class th
        finally {

            DbUtil.close(connection);
            DbUtil.closePreparedStatement(statement);

        }
```

Comment: Have you posted the entire error?

Comment: does your jdbc driver/database support batching?

Comment: Did you want `statement.addBatch()` rather than `statement.addBatch(query)` ?

Comment: Which db are you using ? Because batch is not supported in all the database engines

Comment: Jabir, I am using Oracle 11g. Glenn I don't know much differnt about addBatch() and addBatch() with paramenter. I am learning from [link] (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-batch-processing.htm) BevynQ I do not know if my JDBC driver or database support batching. I thought all Oracle JDBC supports batching.

Comment: PM 77-1, Here is the error java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported feature. The rest are SQL throws from JDBC. I.E oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)

Comment: Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611202/execute-batch-with-oracle-prepared-statement

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch%28%29

Comment: PM 77-1 I used addBatch() before and I got 2nd error(execute cannot be empty) that I mentioned above. P.S I have two different Update statements in property file though.

Comment: I think i am calling addBatch() or using it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing together methods of [`Statement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch%28%29) and [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch%28%29) classes:

- `(addBatch(String sql)` belongs to `Statement` and **cannot be called on a `PreparedStatement` or `CallableStatement`**
- `addBatch()` is to be used with **`PreparedStatement`** (as your tutorial shows).

Oracle implements both it's own and *standard* (JDBC 2.0) batch processing.  From the [Standard Update Batching docs](http://www.comp.dit.ie/btierney/oracle11gdoc/java.111/b31224/oraperf.htm#i1059053):

> In Oracle JDBC applications, update batching is intended for use with
>   prepared statements that are being processed repeatedly with different
>   sets of bind values.

Comment: I tried addBatch without parameter and I got SQL statement to execute cannot be empty or null error.

Comment: Oops...I found my error. There is a typo in my property file.